# Firebase Deep Linking (Share with images)

Tags: android, firebase, deep-linking

I am looking to use firebase for deep linking using dynamic links. I have one question to those who have worked with it before,

Is it possible to share the link with the image (important), for example, if I am sharing a product then product image should also be shown along with URL, wherever(any other app like WhatsApp) I am sharing it

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking about this field: https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/create-manually?authuser=0#social-params when you are creating dynamic links in firebase console you can attached picture here:
[image]